# Running Golang server on Windows Server IIS with reverse proxy(configuring web.config)

Tags: go, iis, web-config

I am new to Windows servers, however, I am a bit experienced on the linux side.

I am trying to run some golang servers on windows. They have been on linux for a while.

I am using the examples on the following links for my `web.config`:

https://medium.com/@mossila/running-go-behind-iis-ce1a610116df

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath=".\app.exe" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

https://alex.domenici.net/archive/deploying-a-go-application-on-windows-server-using-iis-and-a-reverse-proxy.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>                 
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:9000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

One example runs a golang app as a normal ASP.NET Core exe app. The downside is that I have to use `ASPNETCORE_PORT` in my application to get the exact port.

The other one uses a reverse proxy on an already manually started Golang application.

**My challenge**

My challenge is to combine both of these two `web.config` files so that the first part starts my Golang server. The second part reverse proxies into my already started server.

I am not sure on how the order of events happen in the config file.

Comment: All your doubts will be gone if you read the history behind it https://halfblood.pro/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/ Sadly none of the other posts gave you the whole picture.

Comment: Are you saying that it is not possible? What about running same setup in a windows container environment?

Comment: I wonder which part of my writing gave you that conclusion? You need nothing but just HttpPlatformHandler.

Comment: @LexLi, unfortunately I am unable to use `%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%` . It doesn't seem to work for me. The server just hangs up when I use it. `port := os.Getenv("ASPNETCORE_PORT")` on the other hand works very well on my Golang server.

Comment: I wonder if that's caused by improper installation of HttpPlatformHandler but without accessing your machine it is hard to tell.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this. I was finally able to get it to work if I set `%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%` as an argument. It does not work as an environment variable.  My other manually entered environment variables work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Googled "run golang in iis", I found there are two ways to achieve your goal:

1. Run your Go app as a Windows service. Serve directly or via reverse proxy like the IIS ARR module.
2. Run your Go app behind IIS using the httpPlatformHandler.

For ASP.NET Core, the handler that handles the request is ASPNetCoreModule2. For Node on Windows, it’s IISNode. For all other use HTTPPlatformHandler. Similarly, for GoLang, HttpPlatformHandler is the recommended proxy.

So, the best approach would be to use something like this:

```
<handlers>  
  <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />  
</handlers>  
<httpPlatform processPath=".\app.exe" startupTimeLimit="60" />
```

Rreference documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/windows-server-azure-pack/mt125371(v=technet.10)

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to use `%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%` . It doesn't seem to work for me. The server just hangs up when I use it. `port := os.Getenv("ASPNETCORE_PORT")` on the other hand works very well on my Golang server.

Comment: Are there any relevant error messages in the IIS logs and Windows Event Viewer. You may be able to get more help by sharing more details about IIS configuration and Go application setup.